# Python matplotlib not saving charts files

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have historic data on my stock holdings in a database. The object here is to create two charts and save each to png files. I read the data from the db into a pandas dataframe to build the charts. The code runs cleanly - no errors. I see the charts when I run it in Spyder, but nothing is saved. Here is a brief summary of what I'm doing:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
... some code
df['Price'].plot(ax=ax1, title=title1)
plt.savefig(figName1, bbox_inches='tight')
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
... some code
df['% Price'].plot(ax=ax2, title=title2)
df['% S&P'].plot(ax=ax2)
plt.savefig(figName2, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Is there something wrong with this approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. There was nothing wrong with the code shown. The problem was with the format of the figName1 and figName2 addresses. Embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you call `DataFrame.plot()` it returns a numpy array of matplotlib.axes.Axes objects. Try to use `get_figure()` like this:

```
fig1 = df['Price'].plot(ax=ax1, title=title1).get_figure()
fig1.savefig(figName1, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Or in one line:

```
df['Price'].plot(ax=ax1, title=title1).get_figure().savefig(figName1, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm afraid it didn't help.

Comment: Are you running it from jupyter notebook?

Comment: What is precisely the content of figName1?

Comment: It was figName1 = rf'C:\Users\David\StockData\figures\{tstr}1.png' . I changed it to rf'C:/Users/David/StockData/figures/{tstr}1.png' and it works fine.